# Unity3D: Difference in results between GetComponent(string) and GetComponent(Type)?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have script with the following code called in `Start()`

```
GameObject newTerrain = Instantiate(terrainPrefab);
if (newTerrain.GetComponent<Terrain>()) // Returns true
    Debug.Log("I am type");
if (newTerrain.GetComponent("Terrain")) // Returns false
    Debug.Log("I am string");
```

While `Debug.Log` is showing me the `I am type` output, it does not show me the second one. I need to use `GetComponent(string)` later on in my code, but it is not working.

What is causing this difference and is there a solution/workaround for this?

Edit:

So after reading some of the comments and suggestions, i tried both `newTerrain.GetComponent("Terrain") != null` and
`newTerrain.GetComponent("Terrain") as Terrain` in the `if` statement, but both still returned false.

The only reason why I'm trying GetComponent(string) is because I'm trying to learn object pooling and [the tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/847-object-pooling-in-unity) provided the following code:

```
public GameObject GetPooledObject(string type)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < pooledObjects.Count; i++)
    {
        Debug.Log(pooledObjects[i].GetComponent(type));
        if (!pooledObjects[i].activeInHierarchy && pooledObjects[i].GetComponent(type))
        {
            return pooledObjects[i];
        }
    }

    foreach (ObjectPoolItem item in itemsToPool)
    {
        if (item.objectToPool.GetComponent(type))
        {
            if (item.shouldExpand)
            {
                // Create 5 for shits and giggles
                for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
                {
                    GameObject obj = Instantiate(item.objectToPool);
                    obj.SetActive(false);
                    pooledObjects.Add(obj);
                }

                return pooledObjects[pooledObjects.Count - 1];
            }
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

I changed up some of the stuff but the bulk of it remains the same. The `Debug.Log` in *this* function returns a `null` as well, even when i can literally see in the inspector that is has the `Terrain` component attached

Comment: `newTerrain.GetComponent("Terrain") as Terrain` just a suggestion, but try that, as i've only ever really seen the `getComponent(string className)` used with a cast attached

Comment: you know that you could also make `Terrain terrainPrefab` and than use `Terrain nwTerrain = Instantiate(terrainPrefab);` so you don't even need to call `GetComponent` at all?

Comment: Tested fine. Please posted all your test code.

Comment: @Gibbon it should return a `Component` so if just checking for existence it should work without the typecast. So that's actually the answer to whats the diference: The one returns a `Component` the first one returns a `Terrain`.

Comment: did you try to explicitely use `!= null` ?

Comment: @AlexWei that was all that i tested. One `if` statement returned `true` while the other returned `false` even though theoretically, they should both return `true`

Comment: You could also use either the version with a. `Type` as pareter like `GetComponent(Terrain)` or make the whole object pooling method generic like `GetPooledObject<T>() where T : Component { ... }` and than use `GetCompoment<T>()` again ... Though still strange the string version doesn't work for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual answer to the title "What's the difference" would be:

```
newTerrain.GetComponent("Terrain")
```

returns a `Component` reference while

```
newTerrain.GetComponent<Terrain>()
```

returns a `Terrain` reference.

So for actually using the reference you would have to typecast the first one like

```
(Terrain) newTerrain.GetComponent("Terrain")
```

---

However both have the operator `bool` (since `Terrain` inherits from `Behaviour` which inherits from `Component` which inherits from `Object`) so for just checking the existence, both should exactly behave the same way ... except that the `string` version is slower.

So it stays strange that the overload taking `string` doesn't behave as expected.

---

As alternative you could also use either the overload with a `Type` as parameter like

```
public GameObject GetPooledObject(Type type)
{
    ... GetComponent(type)
}
```

and use

```
GameObject newTerrain = ObjectPool.Instance.GetPooledObject(typeof(Terrain));
```

or make the whole object pooling method generic again like

```
public GameObject GetPooledObject<T>() where T : Component 
{
    ... GetCompoment<T>()
}
```

and use

```
GameObject newTerrain = ObjectPool.Instance.GetPooledObject<Terrain>();
```

Comment: when using newTerrain.GetComponent<Terrain>() it returns an Component from Type "Terran". When calling the other Methods/Overloads you have to cast it by your self to its targettype. Also Keep in mind that the Overload with string is the slowest one for getting a Component because of reflection is used to get the type and instance from a given string and a additional casting/boxing to your target Type

Comment: But why do they *not* behave the same way, where one statement returns true and the other, false?

Comment: So i just tried the `GetPooledObject(Type type)` but `GameObject newTerrain = ObjectPool.Instance.GetPooledObject(Terrain)` gives me [CS0119](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0119)

Comment: You have to use `typeof(Terrain)`

Answer (score -1):

I can't see GameObject.GetComponent(string component) in documentation. Guess it is deprecated.
I'll suggest you to use reflection instead.

Comment: [Last overload at the bottom](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.GetComponent.html)

Comment: Advising to use reflection for something this straightforward is not good. You should use the method that uses the type.

Comment: Yeah, reflection is bad performance wise. But it works, and bad answer is better than no answer at all, as it was when I answered it.